# How do I set desired caps in Appium Python Client 3.0.0?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, appium, winappdriver

Due to incompatabilites older versions of Appium and Selenium I have decided the only way forward is to update both of them to the latest versions. I was previously running: Appium-Python-Client==2.2.0, selenium==3.14.1. I am now running Appium-Python-Client==3.0.0, selenium==4.12.0 and I can no longer set desired caps.

I used to run appium like so

```
os.startfile(self.winappdriver_location)
desired_caps = {'app': self.app_location, 'platformName': "Windows", 'deviceName': "WindowsPC"}
self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723", desired_caps)
self.driver.w3c = False
```

However running this returns that desired caps is not expected, I have thus tried using the options parameter as below but with no luck

```
os.startfile(self.winappdriver_location)
options = WindowsOptions()
options.platform_name = "Windows"
options.app = self.app_location
self.driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4723", options=options)
self.driver.w3c = False
```

This returns the following exception

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Bad capabilities. Specify either app or appTopLevelWindow to create a session`

I have tried the example here https://github.com/appium/appium-windows-driver but get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Use this in new Appium-Python-Client 3.0.0 version, it worked for me

```
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.common import AppiumOptions
desired_cap = {
        "udid": f"{serial}",
        "platformName": "Android",
        "adbExecTimeout": 300000
   }
option = AppiumOptions().load_capabilities(desired_cap)
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor=f"http://localhost:4723/wd/hub",options=option)
```